# CORS error when use cors middleware in an api built with node.js and Express

Tags: firebase, express, cors, google-cloud-functions

I am new to node and express. I have encountered a cors error when I am building a very simple API. I have tried several hours to solve it in different method but none of these work.

Here's my approach

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();

app.use(cors({ origin: true }));

app.get('/api', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello');
});

exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

and got 4 errors all about :

http://localhost:3000 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

I have also tried several other some methods like this:

```
var allowCrossDomain = function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Cache-Control");
    next();
};
app.use(allowCrossDomain);
```

Which gives me the same error.
I am using Firebase Cloud Function to deploy this api, because the code is so simple so I really can not figure out which part is not doing right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CORS is always a sticky situation, but in this case, I think I might be able to help. When you run `firebase deploy` you should see your endpoint get deployed. If it's the first time you are deploying that function, it should print out that new function's full URL in the console, it usually looks something like this:

```
https://us-central1-your-project-name.cloudfunctions.net/apiEndpointName
```

If you've already deployed it, you can see the function's full URL in the Firebase console -> Functions -> Dashboard

That URL is the normal public API endpoint or "HTTP-trigger" for that function. If you would use Postman to make a GET request to that URL, you should expect to receive your `Hello` response. (*Or if you visited that URL in your browser, your browser would make a GET request to that URL, you should get your `Hello` response there too*)

The problem comes when you want to access it from your deployed/hosted website. You need to tell the hosting portion of Firebase to route any traffic for `/api` to your function - your Firebase hosting should **not** try to resolve the `/api` route as a normal HTML page deployed along-side the primary index.html file... instead it should direct any traffic for `/api` to the cloud function `api`

So, you need to tell Firebase to direct any traffic for `/api` to the cloud function, not hosting. You give Firebase commands/configuration in the `firebase.json` file... in this case, under a section named "rewrites" like this:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",

    // Add the following rewrites section *within* "hosting"
    "rewrites": [ {
      "source": "/bigben", "function": "bigben"
    } ]

  }
}
```

Check out [this documentation link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions#direct_hosting_requests_to_your_function) where it explains all that^^

Once you've done that, redeploy everything, and now you should be able to visit `/api` in your browser and trigger the function. **NOTE** Unless you are using `firebase serve` you should visit the route on the *deployed website*, not localhost. Check out [this link for more details](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator#use_firebase_serve_for_https_functions) on `firebase serve`.